# Why does Timer thread sometimes not get started when starting an app in Libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

Sometimes when my Activity gets started, the Libgdx's Timer thread is not started at all (I figured this out by attaching a breakpoint) and all the timer functionalities don't work (https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html). This doesn't happen consistently. Is this a known bug?

Comment: Timer executes the tasks in the main thread itself.

Comment: But it does the scheduling in its own thread